# Replace specific parts of a string based on array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array 1 and Array 2. New values will be added to the Array 1 whenever a user input/search something from the input field. When the user click search, the Array 2 will be populated with the search results that contains values in the Array 1.

Ex: Search `let query = "I am going to the ground and play basketball";`

```
Array_1 = ["I am going to the ground and play basketball"];
```

*Service call happening*
Returns:

```
Array_2 = [{name: "ground", start:18, end: "23"}, {name: "basketball", start:"34", end: "43"}];
```

Now I need to create a new string with values from Array 2 based on their charAt values or substr, like below:

`string = "I am going to the <span>ground</span> and play <span>basketball</span>"`; - Or it can be a new array, doesn't matter.

How to achieve this?

Tried:

```
const newString = Array_2.map(obj => {
  let tempStr = `<span>${Array_1[Array_1.length-1].substr(obj.start, obj.end)}</span>`;


  if (tempStr) {
    Array_1[Array_1.length-1] = tempStr;
  }
});

      console.log(Array_1, newString, 'testing');
```

But obviously not getting the expected values.

Comment: You could just replace those words with the words surrounded with span tags...

Answer (score 0):

Using [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
var Array_1 = ["I am going to the ground and play basketball"]
var Array_2 = [{name: "ground", start:18, end: "23"}, {name: "basketball", start:"34", end: "43"}]

var replacer = str => '<span>' + str + '</span>'
  
var result = Array_1.map((string, index) => {
  var position = 0
  var replen = replacer('').length
  
  Array_2.forEach(i => {
    // before + replacer + after
    string = string.substring(0, +i.start + position) + replacer(i.name) + string.substring(+i.end + position + 1)
    position += replen
  })
  
  return string
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, User863, It works. But the problem is I have an Onchange function in the search field that sets/pushes new data into Array_1. So once I search and change the value in my search field, the whole thing messes up. How to fix that?